# Colab matplotlib plot style unexpected behaivor

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I'm getting some unexpected behavior when setting the matplotlib style in Google Colab. Whether or not `plt.style.use` is called in the first cell (which also has the `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` import) or if it's called in a subsequent cell determines whether or not all of the style settings are correctly set.

NOTE: I'm referring to a fresh kernel, so in order to reproduce this behavior restart the kernel for each condition. Also, this behavior is not occurring in JupyterLab on my local machine (the style is set correctly regardless of where `plt.style.use` is called).

If the `plt.style.use` is called in a cell after the imports then everythign is set correctly:

[image]

However, if `plt.style.use` is called in the first cell with the imports then only some of the style settings are set and others are not:

[image]

I like to have all my imports and global settings together in the first cell, so it would be great to figure out how to get this working correctly. I'd appreciate any insights anybody might have. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code; paste it. It makes it difficult to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, and I can confirm that I got the same results. I also tried with different styles and plotting with a pandas df and seaborn. Strangely though, if you put all the code into the first cell block it all runs as expected.

Probably a bug -- [post an issue on thir github](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues).